# Can´t find Google Play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I installed Google Play services via Eclipse and the SDK Manager, everything went right. Now, I wanted to add the library to my project like it is said on the official website, but I can´t find it.

There is no folder "extras" in the Android SDK or on my PC. 
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the extras using SDK Manager? There's another set of packages on the very bottom of the list.

Comment: Yes, I´m sure, I installed "Android Support Library" in the extras!

Comment: There is no reason for an extras folder to be missing from your adt directory if you downloaded google play services through your sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as you, sorted it by updating my Android SDK tools to rev. 23, my Android SDK platform tools to Rev 20, and restarting the SDK manager.

Happy coding.